# can't save event aura:handler for an event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Going the the lightning trailhead I'm at the challenge for camping list events. Everything is done in the CampingForm and all seems to work

In the form component

```
<aura:registerEvent name="addItem" type="c:addItemEvent"/>
```

the form controller validates and all works and calls this helper

```
createItem : function(component, citem) {
    var createEvent = component.getEvent("addItem");
    createEvent.setParams({"item":citem});
    createEvent.fire();
}
```

All seems to work fine
Now in the campinglist component I need to handle that event
When I add this and try to save it

```
<aura:handler name="addItem" type="c:addItemEvent" action="{!c.handleAddItem}" />
```

I get this error

'Failed to save undefined: aura:handler has invalid name attribute value: addItem'

Any ideas why it doesn't like this. I'm doing pretty much the exact same thing that works in the expense app so I am at a loss as to why I cannot save this.

Comment: There is a problem with the `<aura:handler/>` syntax, before that can you confirm whether `c:addItemEvent` is an Application or Component event?

Comment: this is the definition of the addItemEvent <aura:event type="COMPONENT" >
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" />
</aura:event> 
what is the problem with the <aura:handler syntax that you see?

Comment: Can you change type to event:
`<aura:handler name="addItem" event="c:addItemEvent" action="{!c.handleAddItem}" />` Does that work?

Comment: Try changing type="c:addItemEvent" to event="c:addItemEvent" - and remove the invalid 'name' attribute.

Comment: Thanks Caspar. I think that was it. Now I'm getting one of those totally generic errors. Error during init [TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined] usually caused by a stupid typing syntax error but at least it is now letting me save the code with the handler tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `addItemEvent` is an **COMPONENT** event. You need to give the name,event and it action attribute.

Looking at your code, changing the type to event would solve the issue.

```
<aura:handler name="addItem" event="c:addItemEvent" action="{!c.handleAddItem}" />
```